# Is the mime type considered when determining whether the response cache is used?

Tags: http, caching

[I'm looking at solving this problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/232556/2331) but one question that has entered my mind while mulling a solution over, is if I used a vendor specific mime type, how does http caching handle that? to fully state the question, if I request at the same URI, with some level of caching, but a different mime type, do http clients in practice notice that the mimetype has changed so that it will make the request with the new mime type? e.g. is this cached differently

```
GET /foo
Accept: application/array+json
```

from this

```
GET /foo
Accept: application/map+json
```

because I'm not willing to accept the same mime type. I'm interested in both the official HTTP spec and what clients actually do in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have read (and implemented up to some extent), resources are cached based on their URL only. The cache does not know about any mime-type.

Using a different URL for every type works good. It also looks neat as compared to adding parameters to the QueryString.

For example:

```
www.example.com/user123
```

should give the default format

```
www.example.com/user123.json
```

should give JSON

```
www.example.com/user123.xml
```

should give XML

It's easy to see what the URLs mean.